# Problems with unicode text

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe3

I use delphi xe3 and i have small problem !! but i don't how to fix it..

problem is with this letter "è" this letter is inside a file path "C:\lène.mp4"

i save this path into a tstringlist , when i save this tstringlist to a file the path will be shown **fine** inside the txt file ..

but when trying to loading it using tstringlist it will be shown as "Ã¨" (showing it inside a memo or int a variable) in this case it gonna be an invalid path ..

but adding the path(string) directly to the tstring list and then passing it to the path variable it works fine

but loading from the file and passing to the path variable it doesnt work (getting "Ã¨" instead of "è")

normally i will work with a lot of uncite string but for i'm struggling with that letter

this will not work ..

```
    var

    resp : widestring;

    xfiles : tstringlist;
    begin

     xfiles := tstringlist.Create;


     try
     xfiles.LoadFromFile('C:\Demo6-out.txt');  // this file contains only "C:\lène.mp4"

     resp := (xfiles.Strings[0]);

// if i save xfiles to a file "path string" will be saved fine ... ! 
     finally
       xfiles.Free ;
     end;
```

but like this it work ..

```
var

resp : widestring;

xfiles : tstringlist;
begin

 xfiles := tstringlist.Create;


 try

xfiles.Add('C:lène.mp4');

 resp := (xfiles.Strings[0]);



 finally
   xfiles.Free ;
 end;
```

i'm really confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should be using `UnicodeString` instead of `WideString`.  `UnicodeString` was introduced in Delphi 2009, and is much more efficient than `WideString`. The RTL uses `UnicodeString` (almost) everywhere it previously used `AnsiString` prior to 2009.

Second, something else introduced in Delphi 2009 is `SysUtils.TEncoding`, which is used for Byte<->Character conversions.  Several existing RTL classes, including `TStrings`/`TStringList`, were updated to support `TEncoding` when converting bytes to/from strings.

What happens when you load a file into `TStringList` is that an internal `TEncoding` object is assigned to help convert the file's raw bytes to `UnicodeString` values.  Which implementation of `TEncoding` it uses depends on the character encoding that `LoadFromFile()` thinks the file is using, if not explicitly stated (`LoadFromFile()` has an optional `AEncoding` parameter). If the file has a UTF BOM, a matching `TEncoding` is used, whether that be `TEncoding.UTF8` or `TEncoding.(BigEndian)Unicode`.  If no BOM is present, and the `AEncoding` parameter is not used, then `TEncoding.Default` is used, which represents the OS's default charset locale (and thus provides backwards compatibility with existing pre-2009 code).

When saving a `TStringList` to file, if the list was previously loaded from a file then the same `TEncoding` used for loading is used for saving, otherwise `TEncoding.Default` is used (again, for backwards compatibility), unless overwritten by the optional `AEncoding` parameter of `SaveToFile()`.

In your first example, the input file is most likely encoded in UTF-8 without a BOM.  So `LoadFromFile()` would use `TEncoding.Default` to interpret the file's bytes.  `Ã¨` is the result of the UTF-8 encoded form of `è` (byte octets `0xC3 0xA8`) being misinterpreted as Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8.  So, you would have to load the file like this instead:

```
xfiles.LoadFromFile('C:\Demo6-out.txt', TEncoding.UTF8);
```

In your second example, you are not loading a file or saving a file.  You are simply assigning a string literal (which is unicode-aware in D2009+) to a `UnicodeString` variable (inside of the `TStringList`) and then assigning that to a `WideString` variable (`WideString` and `UnicodeString` use the same UTF-16 character encoding, they just different memory managements).  So there are no data conversions being performed.

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)